# Alinhar elemento verticalmente abaixo do Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tenho uma página que vou dividir em duas colunas. A coluna da direita deve estar alinhas tanto verticalmente, quanto horizontalmente e não pode criar uma barra de rolagem. Consegui fazer isso, porem como existe uma navbar, a segunda coluna está ficando maior que o tamanho da tela, criando assim a barra de rolagem. Como faço pra centralizar verticalmente essa coluna sem criar a barra de rolagem, levando em conta o tamanho da minha navbar?

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="bg-white">Coluna 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex bg-info justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <p class="bg-white">Coluna 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não encontrei uma maneira "default" de fazer isso... Digo sem precisar de CSS extra...

Mas como vc tem uma altura padrão para a `Navbar`, basta vc descontar essa altura do `height` total... Assim fazendo um `calc` de `(100% - Height da Navbar)` vc "remove" o scroll

Veja o Exemplo, repare que eu coloquei o `height` do `.container` com a classe `.altura` o `height` fica `height: calc(100% - 56px);` onde `56px` é a altura da `navbar`.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.container.altura {
    height: calc(100% - 56px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container altura">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="bg-white">Coluna 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex bg-info justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <p class="bg-white">Coluna 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```